# Expression: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I'm in the process of making a simple game via SFML and have encountered the following error:

**Debug assertation failed!
Expression: vector subscript out of range**

This error only appears when the 'rocket' makes contact with the first 'enemy' whilst there are 3 enemies on screen at the same time. I understand that it has to do with the fact that I'm deleting elements from a vector in a for loop, but can I get a clear answer as to why this error only occurs when there a 3 or more enemies on screen. Also, how could I rewrite my code so that I can remove the 'enemy' elements from the enemies vector without causing an error? Thanks in advance

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++) //This is where the error points to
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++)
        {
            Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];
            Enemy *enemy = enemies[j];

            if (checkCollision(rocket->getSprite(), enemy->getSprite()))
            {
                //hitSound.play();
                score++;
                std::string finalScore = "Score: " + std::to_string(score);
                scoreText.setString(finalScore);
                sf::FloatRect scoreBounds = scoreText.getGlobalBounds();
                scoreText.setOrigin(scoreBounds.width / 2, scoreBounds.height / 2);
                scoreText.setPosition(viewSize.x * 0.5f, viewSize.y * 0.10f);



                rockets.erase(rockets.begin() + i);
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + j);

                delete(rocket);
                delete(enemy);
                if (score % 5 == 0) levelUp();
                printf("rocket intersects with enemy \n");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have stored the enemy and rocket objects in vectors:

```
    std::vector <Enemy*> enemies;
    std::vector <Rocket*> rockets;
```

Here's my entire update function if that helps:

```
void update(float dt)
{
    hero.update(dt);

    currentTime += dt;
    if (currentTime >= prevTime + 1.125f)
    {
        spawnEnemy();
        prevTime = currentTime;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        Enemy *enemy = enemies[i];
        enemy->update(dt);

        if (enemy->getSprite().getPosition().x < 0)
        {
            enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
            delete(enemy);
            gameOver = true;
            gameOverSound.play();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++)
    {
        Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];

        rocket->update(dt);

        if (rocket->getSprite().getPosition().x > viewSize.x)
        {
            rockets.erase(rockets.begin() + i);
            delete(rocket);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++)
        {
            Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];
            Enemy *enemy = enemies[j];

            if (checkCollision(rocket->getSprite(), enemy->getSprite()))
            {
            //hitSound.play();
                score++;
                std::string finalScore = "Score: " + std::to_string(score);
                scoreText.setString(finalScore);
                sf::FloatRect scoreBounds = scoreText.getGlobalBounds();
                scoreText.setOrigin(scoreBounds.width / 2, scoreBounds.height / 2);
                scoreText.setPosition(viewSize.x * 0.5f, viewSize.y * 0.10f);



                rockets.erase(rockets.begin() + i);
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + j);

                delete(rocket);
                delete(enemy);
                if (score % 5 == 0) levelUp();
                printf("rocket intersects with enemy \n");
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        Enemy *enemy = enemies[i];

        if (checkCollision(enemy->getSprite(), hero.getSprite()))
        {
            gameOver = true;
            gameOverSound.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider what happens in the inner loop if `i` is `rockets.size() - 1` and `j` has not yet reached `enemies.size()-1`.   If the inner loop erases `rockets[i]` and `enemies[j]`,  the inner loop body will be executed again and access a non-existent element of `rockets`.   That causes undefined behaviour.    The `if` then dereferences `rockets[i]` (more undefined behaviour) AND, if the test is true,  deletes it - which will almost certainly corrupt memory used by your program.

Comment: In general, try to stay away from erasing elements in a container that you are iterating on.  You have the `erase/remove` idiom that allows erasure of items that fit a certain criteria, all without having to write an erasure loop.

Comment: Also, you could mark the object as "dead" instead of actually deleting them.  Then after the loop(s), simply remove the dead objects using `erase/remove_if`.  That would require adding a `bool` member to each of those classes.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, we would like to see what `Rocket` and `Enemy` are defined as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, how could I rewrite my code so that I can remove the 'enemy'
>   elements from the enemies vector without causing an error?

If you are allowed to change `Rocket` and `Enemy`, the simplest change would be to add a `bool` member to denote if the object is alive or dead.  Then it's just a matter of marking the object as dead without actually erasing the object from the container.  Then after the loop(s), remove the dead objects.

The change required for `Enemy` and `Rocket` classes would be to add a `bool` member that denotes whether the object needs to be erased:

```
class Enemy
{
   bool destroyed;
   //...
   public:
        Enemy() : destroyed(false) {}
        bool is_destroyed() const { return destroyed; }
        void set_destroyed() { destroyed = true; }
};

class Rocket
{
   bool destroyed;
   //...
   public:
        Rocket() : destroyed(false) {}
        bool is_destroyed() const { return destroyed; }
        void set_destroyed() { destroyed = true; }
};
```

Once that change is done, here is a probable code change for the main loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++) 
{
    if ( rockets[i]->is_destroyed() )  // skip if this was destroyed
       continue;        
    for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++)
    {
        if (enemies[j]->is_destroyed())  // skip if this was destroyed
           continue;
        Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];
        Enemy *enemy = enemies[j];
        if (checkCollision(rocket->getSprite(), enemy->getSprite()))
        {
            //hitSound.play();
            score++;
            std::string finalScore = "Score: " + std::to_string(score);
            scoreText.setString(finalScore);
            sf::FloatRect scoreBounds = scoreText.getGlobalBounds();
            scoreText.setOrigin(scoreBounds.width / 2, scoreBounds.height / 2);
            scoreText.setPosition(viewSize.x * 0.5f, viewSize.y * 0.10f);

            // "destroy" these items
            rocket->set_destroyed();
            enemy->set_destroyed();

            if (score % 5 == 0) levelUp();
            printf("rocket intersects with enemy \n");
            break; // since the rocket is destroyed, 
        }
    }
}

// remove the dead items

// first partition the dead items off from the live items
auto iter = std::stable_partition(rockets.begin(), rockets.end(), [](rocket *r) 
                                  {return r->is_destroyed();});

// issue a delete call on these items.
std::for_each(rockets.begin(), iter, [](rocket *r) { delete r; });

// now erase from the container
rockets.erase(rockets.begin(), iter);

// do similar for the enemies container
auto iter2 = std::stable_partition(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [](enemy *e) 
                                  {return e->is_destroyed();});
std::for_each(enemies.begin(), iter2, [](enemy *e) { delete e; });
enemies.erase(enemies.begin(), iter2);
```

Basically we mark the items to destroy, and then we deal with them after the loop is completed.  The way we deal with them is to partition the dead items using `std::stable_partition`, call `delete` on each of the items on the left of the partition, and then finally erase them from the container.

The reason I didn't simply use `std::remove_if` is that the `remove_if` algorithm invalidates the items that are to be removed, thus attempting to issue a `delete` call will result in undefined behavior.  So partitioning off the "dead" items first, `delete`-ing them second, and then finally erasing them IMO is safer.